# Detecting change of focus on jpanel

Tags: java, swing, focus, jpanel

I have a JTabbedPane. On this component are four JPanels. On each of those panels there is a scrollPanel. Finally, on each scrollPanel is another JPanel. I need to keep track of which of these final JPanels is displayed at any moment.

So I created a class variable called activePanel. For each of the final JPanels, I have a focus event method set so that when the panel gets the focus, this variable is set accordingly. For example:

```
private void pnlAdditionFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        activeTab = "pnlAddition";
        System.out.println(activeTab);
    }
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working as I had hoped. Can somebody suggest what I should do to keep track of this? Thank you.

Comment: `JPanel` is not focusable by default.  Wouldn't it be easier to track the selected tab?

Comment: Yes, that's a much better idea. I didn't know you could do that. It's working now. If you want to add this as an answer, I'll accept it as the solution.  Thanks!!

Comment: Can do, fattened it out a little to... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JPanel` is not focusable by default.

Instead you should keep track of the selected tab

Check out [How to use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for more information